# Interpolation not working in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {SpsheetService} from './spsheet.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
 selector: 'my-spsheet',
 template: `
             <button id="fetch" (click)="reloadData()">Reload Data</button>
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="#head of heads">
                        {{head | async}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#dat of data">
                    <td *ngFor="#head of heads" contenteditable="true">
                        {{dat.head | async}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        `,
providers: [SpsheetService]
 })

export class SpsheetComponent {
    data:any[];
    heads:string[];
    otherdata:string[];
    constructor(private _http:Http,private _spservice:SpsheetService){}

    reloadData(){
        this._spservice.fetchData()
            .subscribe(function(data) 
            {
                var me =this;
                me.data =[];
                me.data = data;
                me.heads = Object.keys(data[0]);
                var len = me.heads.length;
                console.log(me.heads);

            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Completed'));
    }


 }
```

I am loading data from a JSON file and structuring it into an HTML table. I am able to fetch the data and also structure it but the problem is it wont reflect as an HTML table, ie interpolation isn't working. Although the variables are carrying there respective values.

Comment: You have an extra backtick!!?

Comment: I  was actually removing the styles array to simplify it for this forum. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

use arrow functions instead to keep the context of 'this' intact.

```
reloadData() {
            this._spservice.fetchData()
                .subscribe((data) => {
                    this.data = [];
                    this.data = data;
                    this.heads = Object.keys(data[0]);
                    var len = this.heads.length;
                    console.log(this.heads);
                },
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('Completed'));
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't affect it any way, they are just two different styles of writing the same thing, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You have got an Extra BackTick that is causing the entire code to be a string. Just remove that. Copy paste this code below:-

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {SpsheetService} from './spsheet.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
 selector: 'my-spsheet',
 template: `
             <button id="fetch" (click)="reloadData()">Reload Data</button>
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="#head of heads">
                        {{head | async}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#dat of data">
                    <td *ngFor="#head of heads" contenteditable="true">
                        {{dat.head | async}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        `,
],
providers: [SpsheetService]
 })

export class SpsheetComponent {
    data:any[];
    heads:string[];
    otherdata:string[];
    constructor(private _http:Http,private _spservice:SpsheetService){}

    reloadData(){
        this._spservice.fetchData()
            .subscribe(function(data) 
            {
                var me =this;
                me.data =[];
                me.data = data;
                me.heads = Object.keys(data[0]);
                var len = me.heads.length;
                console.log(me.heads);

            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Completed'));
    }


 }
```

Comment: It might be while posting it on this forum, that isn't a problem.

Comment: Can you provide a sample. On Plunkr... Since I am not able to see the data as such, is that possible for you?

Comment: Sure, here is the data I am fetching: [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "type": "donut",
   "name": "Cake",
   "image": "images/0001.jpg",
   "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/0001.jpg"
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "type": "gun",
   "name": "AK47",
   "image": "images/0001.jpg",
   "thumbnail": "images/thumbnails/0001.jpg"
  }
]

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around it, it was actually an issue with 'this' instance of the subscriber.

The actual correct code is:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {SpsheetService} from './spsheet.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
 selector: 'my-spsheet',
 template: `
             <button id="fetch" (click)="reloadData()">Reload Data</button>
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="#head of heads">
                        {{head}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#dat of data">
                    <td *ngFor="#head of heads" contenteditable="true">
                        {{dat[head]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        `,
providers: [SpsheetService]
 })

export class SpsheetComponent {
    data:any[];
    heads:string[];
    otherdata:string[];
    constructor(private _http:Http,private _spservice:SpsheetService){}

    reloadData(){
        var me =this;
        me._spservice.fetchData()
            .subscribe(function(data) 
            {
                me.data =[];
                me.data = data;
                me.heads = Object.keys(data[0]);
                var len = me.heads.length;
                console.log(me.heads);

            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Completed'));
    }


 }
```

Comment: use arrow functions instead to keep the context of 'this' intact. Like this .subscribe((data) => 
            {
                this.data =[];
                this.data = data;
                this.heads = Object.keys(data[0]);
                var len = this.heads.length;
                console.log(this.heads);

            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Completed'));